# Blank Woocommerce Checkout Page

Tags: wordpress, ssl, woocommerce

Firstly I am sorry if this subject is off-topic.

I have a simple e-commerce website based on Wordpress (+Woocommerce). I use a credit card module named iyzico for Checkout page. But When I go to checkout page I am having this problem.

[image]

When I check "system analyze" in Woocommerce in WP backend panel there is one error like this :

```
SoapClient:     ✕ Your server does not have the SoapClient class enabled - some gateway plugins which use SOAP may not work as expected.
```

I think the main problem is that there is not SSL certificate connected the domain in the server. But interesting thing is that was working checkout page with paying with credit card.

What should I do ? The hosting company should make active SOAP plugin on the server or most logically must I buy a SSL certificate to resolve all these ?

PS : I must resolve untill Sunday night (05 june)

Thank you very very much

Comment: If you are accepting credit cards, you need an SSL certificate. That is a separate issue from the lack of a SoapClient.

Comment: @helgatheviking Thank you so much your reply. I'll handle SSL cert. until tomorrow. But I wonder how did it work without SSL certificate ?

Comment: Some payment processors apparently work without it, but the information passed to the processor is not secure so hopefully it wasn't real credit card data.

Comment: I don't know because I am new developer on this site. But I saw some orders with Paypal payments but no credit card orders. Anyway, tomorrow my hosting staff are going to connect SSL to my account. Let's see will it work then.

Comment: Your server does not have the SoapClient class enabled .... pretty much explains it for you, soap is not enabled. Nothing to do with ssl (once you clear this error, there will be an issue with ssl if the gateway is any good).

Comment: Thank you @David Well then they need to activate SoapClient in the server ? And SSL issue will be also resolve ! Is that true ?

Comment: They are separate issues. You need activate SoapClient *and* install SSL.